# how to select whole range to reduce the following program

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

**I tried to select whole data range ("B:ZZ") instead of ("B1:ZZ1"),("B2:ZZ2")... and ("A:A") instead of ("A1"),("A2")... but its not working hence i need to call each time.The program copy data from column "A" to range "B-ZZ" only if cell has previous value = 1

I am finding ways to reduce this program so that in future 100s of data can be analyse in minutes. thanks..**

```
Sub getdata()
For Each cell In Range("B1:ZZ1")
    If cell.Value = 1 Then
        cell.Value = Range("A1")
        Call runme2
        Call runme3
        Call runme4
        Call runme5
        Call runme6
        Call runme7
        Call runme8
        Call runme9
        Call runme10
    Exit Sub
    End If
Next cell
End Sub

Sub runme2()
For Each cell In Range("B2:ZZ2")
    If cell.Value = 1 Then
        cell.Value = Range("A2")
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next cell
End Sub

Sub runme3()
For Each cell In Range("B3:ZZ3")
    If cell.Value = 1 Then
        cell.Value = Range("A3")
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next cell
End Sub

Sub runme4()
For Each cell In Range("B4:ZZ4")
    If cell.Value = 1 Then
        cell.Value = Range("A4")
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next cell
End Sub

Sub runme5()
For Each cell In Range("B5:ZZ5")
    If cell.Value = 1 Then
        cell.Value = Range("A5")
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next cell
End Sub

Sub runme6()
For Each cell In Range("B6:ZZ6")
    If cell.Value = 1 Then
        cell.Value = Range("A6")
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next cell
End Sub

Sub runme7()
For Each cell In Range("B7:ZZ7")
    If cell.Value = 1 Then
        cell.Value = Range("A7")
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next cell
End Sub

Sub runme8()
For Each cell In Range("B8:ZZ8")
    If cell.Value = 1 Then
        cell.Value = Range("A8")
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next cell
End Sub

Sub runme9()
For Each cell In Range("B9:ZZ9")
    If cell.Value = 1 Then
        cell.Value = Range("A9")
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next cell
End Sub

Sub runme10()
For Each cell In Range("B10:ZZ10")
    If cell.Value = 1 Then
        cell.Value = Range("A10")
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the same job as yours.

```
Option Explicit

Sub WriteData()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim C As Variant
    Dim R As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For R = 1 To 10
        With ActiveSheet
            Set Rng = Range(.Cells(R, "B"), .Cells(R, "ZZ"))
            C = Application.Match(1, Rng)
            If Not IsError(C) Then
                Rng.Cells(C).Value = .Cells(R, "A").Value
            End If
        End With
    Next R
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note that the 1 which the Match function looks for must be a number. If it is a string in your worksheet, use "1" instead of the plain 1. As a further note, I was surprised that the code didn't replace the first 1 encountered when there were more than one. Perhaps this has to do with the large size of your row (ZZ = 702).

Comment: appreciating your fast respose

Comment: but this need some adjustments as data starts paste to last column instead of "B" column. I tried "" instead of 1 but not working..

Comment: If `1` doesn't work you should try `"1"`. Either way, the `1` or `"1"` will be replaced with the value in column A. The code will only write to the last column if you search for `""`.